# Changing github credentials for Jenkins

Tags: git, github, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am a new user to Jenkins, so please bear with me.

The employee who set up Jenkins for us quit and we removed his access to our github repo. But he had configured our automated build to access git as himself, so of course that is failing now. I went into the project settings and added a new credential for a user that does have access to our github repo, along with their github password, and I installed that user's ssh key to github. Now when the build runs I get this:

Permission denied (publickey).

What else do I have to do to switch the user that accesses our repo for builds? How can I see what it's getting "Permission denied" on?

Comment: Note you don't need to provide a GitHub password if you've setup a GitHub SSH key (which defeats the purpose of the key). Where did you try to add the GitHub password?

Comment: In the credentials section of the project's configuration.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To setup a user's GitHub SSH key on Jenkins:

1. [Add your user's SSH key to the GitHub account](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account/).
2. In your Jenkins job's configuration, go to **Source Code Management > Git**.
3. Verify that **Repository URL** is the GitHub SSH URL (and not HTTPS).
4. Next to **Credentials**, click **Add**. (Note you can also modify these keys as admin from **Manage Jenkins > Manage Credentials**.)
5. In the **Add Credentials** dialog, fill in the fields as follows:

   - **Kind** - SSH username with private key
   - **Username** - *<GitHub username>*
   - **Private key** - Enter directly
   - **Passphrase** - *<SSH key's passhrase if needed (or blank)>*
   - **Description** - *<Any description for this key>*
6. Copy and paste the contents of the GitHub user's private key file into the textbox for **Private key**. This should begin with `--BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY--` and end with `--END RSA PRIVATE KEY--`.

   It should look like this:
   [image]
7. Click **Add**. This adds the credential to the **Credentials** dropdown.
8. In the **Credentials** dropdown, select the newly added key, identified by the previously entered username and description. Upon selecting the key, Jenkins should show you an error message inline if the key were invalid (in which case I recommend verifying the public key was entered correctly in GitHub and the private key in Jenkins).
9. Save the job configuration.

Comment: Newton's 4th law: Never use an individual's key pair when it comes to some infrastructure setup things like the CI-CD system or anything. Create an abstract user that will not be affected by such instances of leaving the company or ran over by a truck. Generate the key-pair for this arbitrary user and use it.

Comment: Which version of Jenkins is this for?